# How to push the values from 2 different inputs into an array set like this ["one", 2]

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I have two user inputs:

`userInput1`: type of activity (eg.swimming)
`userInput2`: number of hours spend on the activity (2)

I wanna collect these input values to create a dynamic chart using google charts API that takes in predefined format like this,

```
[["swimming", 2], ["twerking", 10]]
```

I'm using vanilla `JS` with focus on `ES6`, so I tried with `map` and `reduce` but feeling very stuck. Documentation from Google Charts API below:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Pizza');
data.addColumn('number', 'Populartiy');
data.addRows([
    ['Pepperoni', 33],
    ['Hawaiian', 26],
    ['Mushroom', 22],
    ['Sausage', 10], // Below limit.
    ['Anchovies', 9] // Below limit.
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make an array that will hold those input values.

```
var userData = [];

for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++){
    var userInput1 = ... ; // get the input for the type of activity here
    var userInput2 = ... ; // get the input for number of hours spend on the activity
    var userInputData = [userInput1, userInput2];
    userData.push(userInputData);
}
```

You can then user the "userData" variable as parameters for "addRows" method.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Pizza');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Populartiy');
  data.addRows(userData);
```